# How to select values from a NumPy array by indices in another array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a NumPy vector and a matrix with different values like the following:

```
v = np.array([10, 15, 20, 25])

m = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
              [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4],
              [0.12, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2],
              [0.7, 0.0, 0.2, 0.4]])
```

Additionally, I also have an "index matrix" like this:

```
m_index = np.array([[1, 2],
                    [3, 0],
                    [1, 2],
                    [0, 2]])
```

Now, I'd like to have two new matrices of identical shape with `m_index`.
In the first resulting matrix I need the indexed values from `v` defined by indices in `m_index`:

```
[[15, 20],
 [25, 10],
 [15, 20],
 [10, 20]]
```

In the second resulting matrix I need the indexed values from `m` defined by  indices in `m_index` (each indices in `m_index` refer to a value in the corresponding row in `m`):

```
[[0.2, 0.3],
 [0.4, 0.1],
 [0.8, 0.1],
 [0.7, 0.2]]
```

Comment: Should not the 2nd line you your wanted vector from v be `[25 10]` and not `[10 25]`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [np.take](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) and [np.take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) here, using it like this:

```
v.take(m_index)
```

Output:

```
array([[15, 20],
       [25, 10],
       [15, 20],
       [10, 20]])
```

and

```
np.take_along_axis(m ,m_index, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.2, 0.3],
       [0.4, 0.1],
       [0.8, 0.1],
       [0.7, 0.2]])
```

Comment: The solution doesn't work in case of m.take(m_index) (please compare the last two rows with the expected output).

Comment: I updated my answer. Now the outputs are equal.